# How to remove initial and final digits from strings using bash scripting

Tags: bash, sed

Quite new to bash scripting so If I have a list usually text files each file specific for one country for example USA.txt client addresses with leading ZIP and ending P.O Box (Numbers are masked for privacy) :

```
38495newyork940
454354irvine40404
2333wathington4440
32333california002929
23234dallas4th93303
```

I want to run USA.txt as an argument to a bash script that would remove the leading and final digits from each line. Please note that certain cities or states might have numbers within the names so I want to keep them.

I tried to run it against sed commands but I can't combine the end result I just remove the leading or final numbers with commands like :

for leading digits:

```
sed -r 's/^[0-9]+(.*[^0-9].*)$/\1/g'
```

and for ending digits:

```
sed "s/\([^0-9]\)[0-9]*\s*$/\1/"
```

I need the output like:

```
newyork
irvine
wathington
california
dallas4th
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give `sed` as many commands as you like:

```
$ sed 's/^[0-9]*//; s/[0-9]*$//' USA.txt 
newyork
irvine
wathington
california
dallas4th
```

Or you can do it all in one command:

```
$ sed 's/^[0-9]*\(.*[^0-9]\)[0-9]*$/\1/' USA.txt 
newyork
irvine
wathington
california
dallas4th
```

Comment: and a 3rd way would be `sed -E 's/^[0-9]*|[0-9]*$//g` or `sed -E 's/^[0-9]*|[0-9 ]*$//g'` (OP's sample has spaces at end)

Comment: @Sundeep The spaces seem to be an artifact. They are not there in the edit mode (except for the last sample line).